# Background does not load in github pages

Tags: html, css, git, github, background

My Repo: https://github.com/AbdulXDG/abdulxdg.github.io
I've seen similar questions like this but none of the solutions seem to work. I tried linking the images with the website link, checking for case sensitivities and moving all images into the main folder. all the images except the background work. so what is the problem??

Comment: It sure doesn't look like you did any of the things you said you did. You checked "case sensitivities" but not the actual path?

Comment: I forked your Repo and When I run it the background image is perfectly loaded. what's an issue?

Comment: Ok So how do i fix the 'path' issue. All the other images are loading perfectly only the background has a problem Maybe it is due to my browser.

Comment: Did  the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have **typo** in `url` address in `.banner` class selector.
3rd line `background-image` property.

---

Instead of =>

```
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.75),rgba(0,0,0,0.75)),url(Images/bg.jpg);
```

Change to =>

```
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.75),rgba(0,0,0,0.75)),url(images/bg.jpg);
```

Now it works as we can see ;-)

[image]